# How to authenticate one salesforce org using username and password from another salesforce org with lwc component

Tags: lightning-web-components, integration

I have one requirement that I have one lwc component to display the data of the profile permissions for logged-in salesforce org(org1), and from the same LWC component needs to get the other salesforce org profile permissions without logging out from org 1, and this should be done by using user id and password of salesforce credentials, here there is no scope for connected apps. The interface will look like as image attached to this post[image]

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Note - It is not recommended and not secure to go with UserName and Password approach.**

However for experiment/educational purpose here's one approach-

Instead of Rest API, you can use the SOAP api for authentication. SOAP api supports this way and lot of desktop tools use this.

Example: Force.com IDE with Eclipse allow users to connect using username, password+security token to the org and fetch metadata.

So from LWC you could call apex, that will invoke the SOAP class.

`LoginResult = connection.login(string username, string password);`

Reference Link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm